# How to insert/delete data based on ajax post dynamically triggered by checkboxes (checked or unchecked)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have 1 table that have 1 checkboxes every row, so if 1 data in row checked means insert, and unchecked means delete in table.

here's pic of my table :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB1LS.jpg

this is code of my table (admin/roleaccess) :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <?= $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>

        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Menu</th>
                    <th scope="col">Akses</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php $i = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($menu as $m) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><?= $i; ?></th>
                    <td><?= $m['menu'] ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" <?= check_access($role['id_lvl'], $m['id']); ?> data-role="<?= $role['id_lvl']; ?>" data-menu="<?= $m['id']; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php $i++ ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

my script :

```
<script>
$('.form-check-input').on('click', function() {
    const menuId = $(this).data('menu');
    const roleId = $(this).data('role');

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php base_url('admin/changeAccess'); ?>",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            menuId: menuId,
            roleId: roleId
        },
        success: function() {
            document.location.href = "<?= base_url('admin/roleaccess/'); ?>" + roleId;
        }
    });

});
```

and my function in controller :

```
 public function roleAccess($role_id)
{
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['nama' => $this->session->userdata('nama')])->row_array();
    $data['title'] = 'Akses Role';

    $data['role'] = $this->db->get_where('user_lv', ['id_lvl' => $role_id])->row_array();

    $this->db->where('id != ', 1);
    $data['menu'] = $this->db->get('user_menu')->result_array();

    $this->load->view('templates/intern_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/role-access', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/intern_footer');
}

public function changeAccess()
{
    $menu_id = $this->input->post('menuId');
    $role_id = $this->input->post('roleId');

    $data = [
        'id_lvl' => $role_id,
        'menu_id' => $menu_id
    ];

    $result = $this->db->get_where('user_access_menu', $data);

    if ($result->num_rows() < 1) {
        $this->db->insert('user_access_menu', $data);
    } else {
        $this->db->delete('user_access_menu', $data);
    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Akses diganti !</div>');
}
```

so the problem is when I tried to check the checkboxes the table not updating any data (insert/delete).

I tried to figure out whats the problem is like :

- it successfully trigger the onclick function (because the page
  refresh after checkboxes is checked or unchecked.
- it succesfully pass the menuId & roleId data (which I get the proof from using browser console and add html response in script)

so, I think the problem is on changeAccess function in my controllers but I dont know how to figure it out because I dont understand to dump the data from the ajax or else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify that your checkbox is selected or not in

```
$('.form-check-input').on('click', function() {});
```

by adding following snippet

```
if($(this).is(":checked")){ }
```

Set a flag on the basis of checkbox is checked or not and pass that flag though ajax to insert and delete from table.